# R SQL: Pull data from MySQL for list of ids already in a dataframe

Tags: mysql, sql, r, r-dbi

I have a dataframe in R which contains the output of previous queries. Unfortunately, I cannot do this directly in SQL since it is too slow so I am using the data.table package. The output from the data.table package is a data frame of 50,000 ids. I need to pull all records from the database for each id.

```
# x is a dataframe containing 50,000 ids.
```

Usually, I would do something like,

```
dbGetQuery(con, "Select * from data where id in x")
```

but that won't work. An alternative is to do 50,000 queries in a for loop, but I am thinking that there must be a more efficient method to do this.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: I don't know what MySQL's limit on the number of items in an `IN` clause are, but suspect (??) that it's pretty large. Are you sure you can't just put all or most of them in one `IN` clause? (Another option of course is to push the ids to a temporary table in the db and do a join.)

Comment: what do you mean `but that wont work` ?

Comment: how about if you step back, describe the tables, and what you want to achieve, so we don't go down the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377) path

Comment: dbGetQuery(con, "select * from data where order_id in x"). I get the following error: 

Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'x' at line 1

Comment: You mean something like `subset(data, id == x`)?

Comment: ok, it is a **syntax error**. how about select * from data where order_id in (select order_id from camels where humps=2). Or a join

Comment: For example, x = c(0,1,2,3)

Comment: In order to do `IN` clause queries like this from R, you'll need to explicitly build the query via string concatenation using `paste()` or `sprintf()`.

Comment: joran, can you provide an example? I would be using paste, but running that 50,000 times, once for each id. The main question would be how to pull data for all ids in x at the same time.

Comment: schema published would be helpful. Else telepathy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For example,

```
x <- 0:3
> q <- "select * from table where id in (%s)"
> sprintf(q,paste(x,collapse = ","))
[1] "select * from table where id in (0,1,2,3)"
```

As I mentioned in my comment, some databases have limits on the number of items you can put in the `IN` clause. I'm not familiar enough with MySQL to know what that is, but I'd be willing to bet it's large enough that you could do this in only a handful of queries.

And in many cases this will be less efficient (slower) than having the IDs in a table in the database and doing a join, but sometimes people don't have the access to the database required to accomplish that.

Comment: @quantactuary Out of curiosity, did it accept all 50k in one IN clause, or did you have to split it up?

Comment: Good question - it ran all at once, literally in seconds.

Comment: @joran How can the same thing be done with string type values rather than numeric?

Comment: @VijayBarve e.g. `paste(paste0("'",letters[1:3],"'"),collapse = ",")` just to add the single quotes; again with the usual warnings that this sort of thing should only be done if your db setup is such that SQL injection is not much of a concern.